# Странные подключения с ngrok

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет

Есть скрипт на питоне, используеться для регестрации, должен проверять токен, и если он верный проверять чтоб вход был с компютера с которого токен ввели впервый раз, чтоб токен не использовали сразу много людей.

Но не суть, если работать в локальной сети `127.0.0.1` то все хорошо, но если я подключаю Ngrok, происходят вот такие странности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то что токен и ип пустой не удивительно, ибо их передает Python socket, но то почему они считаються правильный загадка...

PS: если Python сокету отправить пустое место, он выдаст его как неправильный токен

вообщем не столь важно как они считаються, важно то как их убрать

Comment: offtop - правильно будет "правильный" вместо "правельный"

Comment: уже изменил, спасибо

Comment: "почему они считаються правильный" - напрашивается логичный вопрос: а почему они должны считаться неправильными?

Comment: потому что вместо токена и ип адреса передаеться пустое пространство...

Comment: я проверял, если передать пустую переменную, то токен считаеться неправильным